# Tab Wrapping Behavior with CSS and jquery.tools tabs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tabs

I am getting some strange wrapping behavior in Chrome with jquery tools tabs:
[image]

When the  browser is larger, they all just appear in one row.
The CSS for the tabs is:

```
/* root element for tabs  */
ul.tabs {  
    margin:0 !important; 
    padding:0;
    height:30px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #666;       
}

/* single tab */
ul.tabs li {  
    float:left;  
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;  
    list-style-type:none;   
}

/* link inside the tab. uses a background image */
ul.tabs a { 
    float:left;
    font-size:13px;
    display:block;
    padding:5px 30px;   
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #666;  
    border-bottom:0px;
    height:18px;
    background-color:#efefef;
    color:#777;
    margin-right:2px;
    position:relative;
    top:1px;    
    outline:0;
    -moz-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0; 
}

ul.tabs a:hover {
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    color:#333;
}

/* selected tab */
ul.tabs a.current {
    background-color:#ddd;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;   
    color:#000; 
    cursor:default;
}


/* tab pane */
.panes div {
    display:none;
    border:1px solid #666;
    border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;
    min-height:150px;
    padding:15px 20px;
    background-color:#ddd;  
}
```

The Over all structure of this page is:
[image]

Anyone have any suggestions on how I mix fix or work around this?

Comment: Could you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) test case? That would make it much easier for us to test ideas for fixes.

Comment: @thirydot: Test Case http://jsfiddle.net/me9XZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I added `overflow: hidden` to `ul.tabs` to clear the floated elements (tabs).
- I added `border-bottom: 1px solid transparent` to offset the problem, which was having on `ul.tabs a.current` this: `border-bottom:1px solid #ddd`.
- The `border` was making that one tab `1px` higher than the other tabs, but the `1px` of `transparent` border ensures consistent height.
- When you have floated elements that are different heights, you get these sorts of problems.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/me9XZ/3/

I tested in Chrome/Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Give ui.tabs li height.

```
ul.tabs li {  
    height:30px;  
}
```

Comment: Hmm... What this does is make it so it won't wrap assuming I make the width big enough to cover all tabs. However, I am going to have a good amount of tabs, so wrapping is unavoidable I think. And with this, I still get strange behavior as soon as there are enough tabs to cause two rows.

Comment: In that case try taking the height off ul.tabs

Comment: @Ed Fryed: Still no love removing height, see comment on question if you want to play with it in jsfiddle.

Comment: Remove height from ul.tabs and add to ul.tabs li

Comment: Yup, setting an explicit height on `ul.tabs li` will also work. To be honest, it's a less finicky way to solve the problem than my suggestion.

Comment: Can this be adjusted so the contents of the tab are always below the tabs? With it is now, some content will appear on the same row as the tabs.

Comment: @Kyle Brandt: The `overflow: hidden` suggestion from my answer should sort that out.